# Show specific tab when opening the app from notification

Tags: ios, swift, quickblox

I use Quickblox chat system in a project.

User gets push notifications when received a new message.

I want app to show a specific tab if user opened it from a chat push notification.

Should i use `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` delegate fot this purpose or how can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you embed a deep link into your push message and then create a simple routing to navigate around your application. 
For example

```
{
    "aps": 
    {
        "alert": "Message received from Bob"
    }
    "view": "tabs/tab1/vcs/chatVC"
 }
```

You can handle it in 2 places

```
//When the application is truly not loaded
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

    return YES;
}
//Active or background
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

}
```

Comment: i need to get notification text on didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: I edited my post and included the code to get notification text.

Comment: Thanks but can you write it in swift if possible?

Comment: Swift:

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        if let launchOptions = launchOptions {
            let dict: NSDictionary = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as! NSDictionary!
            print(dict)
            
        }
        
        return true
    }

Comment: Could you provide the log?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right.

If your app is not launched (not even suspended in background), the launchOptions will contain the notification payload (key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey`).

Comment: How can i get the text on the notification ?